# How to write only necessary lines from a file into an array in bash script?

Tags: arrays, bash, grep

I wrote the following code to read a file and write it in a list using bash script:

```
index=0
while read line
do
  array[$index]="$line"
  index=$(($index+1))
done < ../../file.xml
```

However, I only need to write lines into the array if they contain the word "icon". An array element should look like this:

```
<icon height="36" width="36" density="ldpi" src="res/icon/android/ldpi.png"/>
```

Could anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: `arr=($(grep -w 'icon' ../../file.xml))`?

Comment: @Wiktor that will read one token per array element, not one line.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In the file have different information, where I need to select lines containing word 'icon'. An element in an array should look like this:<icon height="36" width="36" density="ldpi" src="res/icon/android/ldpi.png"/>

Comment: @tripleee OK, `readarray arr < <(grep -w 'icon'  ../../file.xml)`

Comment: I'm using a later version of bash so I cannot use readarray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivially, with a condition.

```
case $line in *icon*) ... do stuff;;
```

You should probably fix the syntax to use `read -r` and the `index` variable is really unnecessary.

```sh
array=()
while read -r line
do
  case $line in *icon*) array+=("$line");; esac
done < ../../file.xml
```

More sensibly, do it all in one fell swoop, in Bash 4+

```
readarray index < <(grep 'icon'  ../../file.xml)
```

Probably most sensibly, if the file really is XML, use an XML parser like `xmlstarlet` to properly identify and extract the structure you want to examine.

```sh
readarray index < <(xmlstarlet sel -t -m //icon -c . -n ../../file.xml)
```

Comment: the vital part here is really to use a *proper XML parser* for parsing XML, rather than attempting your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
regex="icon"
index=0
while read line
do
  if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
    array[$index]="$line"
    #If you need cut address uncommend next line and comment before line
    #array[$index]="$(sed 's/.*src=\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/' <<< $line)"
    index=$(($index+1))
  fi
done < ../../file.xml
```

Comment: What's with the crazy `sed` script in the assignment? That might be useful for something but wasn't in the requirements.

Comment: transfer "<icon height="36" width="36" density="ldpi" src="res/icon/android/ldpi.png"/>" to "res/icon/android/ldpi.png"

Comment: If not need cut address of image - write only array[$index]=$line

Comment: Šerg, thank you for your help. I got the following output: 
0: <icon
1: height="36"
2: width="36"
3: density="ldpi"
4: src="res/icon/android/ldpi.png"/>
5: <icon
6: height="48"
7: width="48"
....
However, an array element should look like this: 
0: <icon height="36" width="36" density="ldpi" src="res/icon/android/ldpi.png"/>
(Not separately)

Comment: Gera, write simple exapmle of file.xml please